# CSS not updating in GWT

Tags: css, gwt, caching

I'm having difficulty with my GWT 2.4 project. I have a CSS file that I was previously handling with `ClientBundle`:

```
    public interface FooResources extends ClientBundle {
      public static final FooResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(FooResources.class);

      @NotStrict
      @Source("base.css")
      public CssResource baseCss();

      ...
   }
```

Then, in my entry point, I ensured that the CSS was injected:

```
  static {
    FooResources.INSTANCE.baseCss().ensureInjected();
  }
```

However, I found that when I edited `base.css`, nothing changed in my app. So I tried moving `base.css` to the same directory as the base `.html` file, and referencing it the old fashioned way with a `link` tag. However, my changes to the file were still not reflected in what I saw rendered in the browser. (I viewed the CSS file in Chrome's developer console, and still saw the old version.)

I tried clearing Chrome's cache, but that did not resolve the issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: if my CSS is handled through a `ClientBundle`, I need to re-compile GWT before the changes will take effect.

Comment: Or running in DevMode (aka Hosted Mode) you can see the changes without recompiling